# A "combining logic" moment in Kant

Tags: ethics, epistemology, kant, modal-logic, probability

In ["Ethical Theories and Moral Guidance"](https://philpapers.org/archive/VYRETA.pdf), Pekka Väyrynen goes over proposals and arguments concerning the knowability of moral claims. Kant's relevant proposal (in the second *Critique*) is:

> The commonest intelligence can easily and without hesitation see what, on the principle of autonomy of the will, requires to be done; but on supposition of heteronomy of the will, it is hard and requires knowledge of the world to see what is to be done. That is to say, what duty is, is plain of itself to everyone; but what is to bring true durable advantage, such as will extend to the whole of one's existence, is always veiled in impenetrable obscurity; and much prudence is required to adapt the practical rule founded on it to the ends of life, even tolerably, by making proper exceptions. But the moral law commands the most punctual obedience from everyone; it must, therefore, not be so difficult to judge what it requires to be done, that the commonest unpractised understanding, even without worldly prudence, should fail to apply it rightly.

Let *kS* read, "It is known that *S*." After we [combine some logics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-combining/), a quick conversion of the above quote might, then, go:

> **OB***S* → ◊*k***OB***S*

Or (trivially?):

> **OB***S* → □◊*k***OB***S*

**However, Kant's reference to "difficulty" carries connotations of broader degrees of knowability**, in the sense that moral claims would be knowable, but for some the specific process of knowledge-acquisition is more complex, less obvious, etc. than for some other cases. Is a strictly "logical" formalism the best way to develop this talk of variable epistemic difficulty, or would we have to bring in stronger mathematics of probability, or something else more substantially mathematical besides? (Is there such a thing as "epistemic mathematics" specifically? As if we had an "epistemic unit" (or a basic set of epistemic elements, or a category of knowledge with epistemic morphisms, or who knows what!) and operations thereon.)

Comment: Isn't your seek of "epistemic mathematics" in the usual sense just the usual epistemic uni-modal logic, not even multi-modal or combining logics such as your ◊kOB? In terms of modality even the most complicated math sounds straightforward. Only deep philosophical thesis such as Hume's, alethic/physical combo and ethics may be difficult in terms of degrees connotation of knowability.

Comment: To measure this degree, in principle you can choose either combining logic of different k-level operators adding some bridge principles linking them most likely, or you can go probabilistic way like Carnap's degree of confirmation with statistical correlation matrix replacing bridges. The choice lies in your personal penchant to quantify this kind of degree... And I don't think we have an epistemic atom since that's totally determined by its corresponding proposition at the end...

Comment: As you suggest, I'm not sure the modal operators "possibly" and "known" really capture the point. I wonder if this might call for a new modal operator "practically knowable", meaning that a proposition is knowable and that any reasonable, reasonably informed individual is able to know it with a bit of reflection.